# Aura Wrapper to LWC: record-id of lwc to recordId mapping

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, migration, workspaceapi

I have an AuraComponent that wraps an lwc component for the purpose of using the workspace API.  AuraComponent can see the recordId. In LWC component the recordId is always undefined.  I have checked the meta-xml file.  If I directly place myLWC2 in a page via App Builder, it renders {recordId}

**What is missing/incorrect?**

```
<aura:component implements="lightning:isUrlAddressable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,force:hasRecordId" access="global">
    <lightning:workspaceAPI aura:id="workspace"/>

    <c:myLWC2 record-id="{!v.recordId}" onworkspaceAPI="{!c.handleWorkspaceAPI}"></c:myLWC2>

    RecordId: {!v.recordId}
</aura:component>
```

myLWC2.js-meta.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata" fqn="myLWC2">
    <apiVersion>45.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <targets>
        <target>lightning__AppPage</target>
        <target>lightning__RecordPage</target>
        <target>lightning__HomePage</target>
  </targets>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

myLWC2.js:

```
import { LightningElement, track, api } from 'lwc';
import { NavigationMixin } from 'lightning/navigation';

export default class myLWC2 extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {
    @api
    recordId;

}
```

myLWC2.html:

```
<template>
    RecordId: {recordId}
</template>
```

Comment: did you checked record-id in the lwc?

Comment: Answering my own post/question. It was an attribute naming problem: recordId="{!v.recordId}"

Answer (score 4):

Answering my own post/question.  It was an attribute naming problem: recordId="{!v.recordId}"

Somewhere I have seen record-id was mentioned (in some documentation or sample about wrapping lwc components for workspaceAPI usage via Aura component) that made me provide the attribute to be record-id (and not recordId).

> **Hope this helps people to check all the conditions who had similar problems following that documentation or sample**